# How to insert Heading 1 and its index(from the table of content) to the headers in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

I am using:

> Insert > Quick Parts > Field > StyleRef : STYLEREF  "Heading 1"

My "Heading 1" is a numbered list and I want to display the number with the title as well? This solution displays only the title, not the number.

[image]

Comment: You want to save the style of a row from the ToC in the styles bar?

Comment: I am searching for any solution to put text with my index (the way like it is in 
TOC) @BogdanDoicin

Comment: I don't think there is way to do it unless you change how you are numbering sections. I checked the field editing and there are no switches listed that will help. For a simple workaround (I do it if working with style references), don't use auto-numbering, just manually plug in the number for each section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by inserting 2 separate STYLEREF fields - one for number, one for text.

To show the paragraph number, you just need to tick the  box "Insert paragraph number" in the Field options at right-hand side of dialog when inserting your STYLEREF field - or if editing the field code directly, just add the switch \n so it is STYLEREF "Heading 1" \n

Then insert your second STYLEREF field as per normal to get the heading text.